# How to change elasticsearch version in reactive spring data elastic search api?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-data-elasticsearch

spring data elasticsearch uses 7.x client version and my production elasticsearch version is 6.4.2. So I changed the version and got the following exception. How to safely change version in spring data es?

Repopsitory: https://github.com/Yungdi/spring-data-reactive-elasticsearch

```
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate.<init>(ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate.java:108)

The following method did not exist:

    org.elasticsearch.action.support.IndicesOptions.strictExpandOpenAndForbidClosedIgnoreThrottled()Lorg/elasticsearch/action/support/IndicesOptions;

The method's class, org.elasticsearch.action.support.IndicesOptions, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/we/DevEnv/gradle-6.4.1/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.4.2/29a4003b7e28ae8d8896041e2e16caa7c4272ee3/elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar!/org/elasticsearch/action/support/IndicesOptions.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.elasticsearch.action.support.IndicesOptions: file:/Users/we/DevEnv/gradle-6.4.1/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.4.2/29a4003b7e28ae8d8896041e2e16caa7c4272ee3/elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.elasticsearch.action.support.IndicesOptions
```

Answer (score 1):

You can’t use a Elasticsearch 6 cluster with Spring Data Elasticsearch 4 which uses Elasticsearch 7 libraries. The Elasticsearch REST API that is used had breaking changes between version 6 and 7.

You can try to use Spring Data  Elasticsearch 3.2.x which targets 6.8; I currently don’t know if there were breaking changes between Elasticsearch 6.4 and 6.8, you’ll have to try it.

Comment: @YunjinJang did you find a solution to this? also, are you getting the correct mappings with ReactiveElasticsearch?